# Flutter - Custom notification UI with action buttons for background notification

Tags: flutter

I'm building a new video call app using flutter. I'm troubled to create a background notification for call notification UI with the accepting and reject button. I'm using FCM with [flutter local notification](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications). So please guide us If any packages available. Thanks in advance